# Differences of transpose functions in python

Tags: python, numpy, transpose

I am generating a large matrix (100x100, let's call it X) with random numbers, with numpy.matrix() so that I have a numpy.ndarray.

I have been wondering if there are any difference between the two operations:

1. **numpy.transpose(X)**
2. **X.T**

I have measured the time of each operation in a loop with a range of 1000 and it seems that **X.T** is significantly faster than **numpy.transpose(X)**

***Added Benchmarks:***

For a 100x100 matrix I got the following results with **X.T** and **numpy.tranpose(X)**

**In a 10.000 range loop:**

- 7421/10.000: **X.T** fastest
- 1256/10.000: **numpy.transpose(X)** fastest
- 1323/10.000: Same computation time or difference too small to determine

**Added the code below**

```
    import numpy as np
    import time

    np_transpose_count = 0
    T_transpose_count = 0
    equal_count = 0

    for i in range(10000):
       Se = np.random.rand(100,100)

       tic1 =time.clock()
       ST_T = Se.T
       toc1=time.clock()

       tic2 =time.clock()
       ST_np = np.transpose(Se)
       toc2=time.clock()

       if (toc1-tic1) < (toc2-tic2):
           T_transpose_count+=1
       elif (toc1-tic1) > (toc2-tic2):
           np_transpose_count+=1
       else:
           equal_count+=1

    print(T_transpose_count, np_transpose_count, equal_count)
```

Best regards
Whir

Comment: Interesting. I don't understand the units of your benchmark. Could you update to say? On my system, looks like X.T is 20-30% faster than X.transpose() (using %timeit on 100x100 or 10000x10000 array).

Comment: Also, `np.transpose(X)` is 120-130% slower than `x.T` on my system. Maybe there's a small amount of extra overhead for the function call (`x.transpose()` is a function while `x.T` is not). `np.transpose()` is a python function with some wrapping code, so there's some extra overhead there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using Ipython `%timeit` magic I get:

```
In [218]: X=np.ones((100,100))

In [219]: timeit X.T
1000000 loops, best of 3: 379 ns per loop

In [220]: timeit X.transpose()
1000000 loops, best of 3: 470 ns per loop

In [221]: timeit np.transpose(X)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 993 ns per loop

In [222]: timeit X+1
10000 loops, best of 3: 21.6 µs per loop
```

So yes, `.T` is fastest, and the function slowest.  But compare those times with the time for a simple addition

Or a copy or slice

```
In [223]: timeit X.copy()
100000 loops, best of 3: 10.8 µs per loop

In [224]: timeit X[:]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 465 ns per loop
```

Transpose in all its forms returns a new array object, with new `shape` and `strides`, but with a shared data buffer (Look at the `.__array_interface__` dictionary to see that).  So it takes about the same time as other actions that return a `view`.  But none of the transpose functions makes a copy of the data or iterates through it.  So the time differences are just the result of calling over head.

Again with `ipython` magic

```
np.transpose??
def transpose(a, axes=None):
    try:
        transpose = a.transpose
    except AttributeError:
        return _wrapit(a, 'transpose', axes)
    return transpose(axes)
```

So `np.function(X)` ends up calling `X.transpose()`.

I'd have to look at the numpy code, but I recall that `.T` is implemented as an `attribute` (not quite the same as a `property`).  I suspect it is faster because it doesn't use the `axes` parameter, and thus saves a `C` function call or two.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply. It was very useful for my understanding of this.